# Map a decimal column value in result set to column in csv with 2 decimal places only

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, sql-server-2012

In SSIS, i have a select query and one of the column result returned is a decimal value. The statement is similar to

```
select (2*100.0)/19
```

i get

```
10.526315
```

Now, since i need this to be rounded off to two decimal places, used the below format.

```
 select FoRMAT((2*100.0)/19,'N2')
```

i get

```
10.53
```

Now, when i execute the sql on the editor, the expected result is seen. However, when the ssis destination is a csv file, the csv has 12 decimal places

```
10.530000000000
```

What exactly needs to be corrected so that it just shows 2 decimal places

```
 10.53
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the *scale* of your output, assuming you're using a flat file destination. This is under the *Advanced* tab.

[image]

Comment: I saw your suggested edit. I've updated the answer to reflect it